# Using Azure Redis Cache Instances across App Services

Tags: azure, redis, azure-appservice, azure-redis-cache

We are planning to use Azure Cache for Redis service to avoid multiple database operations and improve performance of our Web Apps. We have a few App Services - they are not big and typically run in just a couple of instances. We are wondering if we should create separate instance per App Service (the price can be an overkill for this) or can we share the Redis instance across the App Services.

Comment: `can we share the Redis instance across the App Services.` - that's the whole point of using Azure Cache for Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same REDIS Cache can be used across multiple web apps, but one important consideration to keep in mind is that REDIS is a single threaded service !